# WSGI server that processes request despite client disconnecting? - Python

Tags: python, django, wsgi, uwsgi, gevent

**I need to find a stable wsgi server that won't stop processing requests when client disconnect.**

I'm not sure if uWSGI or gunicorn would fit this criteria.

---

Forgot to add this:

I am also trying to return a response before the request gets processed.

---

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you have to queue what ever you need from the request. Then return something to the client. Have a thread running in parallel processing the queue.

Answer (score 1):

almost all wsgi servers do that. I'm not sure what you mean.

- gunicorn
- paste
- cherrypy
- twisted.web
- apache with mod_wsgi
- werkzeug
- ...

Comment: Tahnks nosklo! last time I tried the requests were not getting processed. Was using gevent. Do you have an idea on what is the bare minimum needed in order for a request to be processed? Ah, also I forgot to add something important in the question!